# Integrating class based Axios request to the hook based code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks

How can I integrate this class based Axios request to the other hook based code that gets data from a Json file? Basically I want to replace data source LOCATIONS with the Axios get request. Thanks.

```
componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-places').then(res => {
    this.setState({
      posts: res.data
    })
  })
}
```

```
import { LOCATIONS } from '../data/data'

    const HomeScreen = props => {
      const renderGridItem = itemData => {
        return (
          <CategoryGridTile
            image={itemData.item.image}
            title={itemData.item.title}

            onSelect={() => {
              props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'Categories',
                params: {
                  locationId: itemData.item.id
                }
              })
            }}
          />
        )
      }

      return (
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          data={LOCATIONS}
          renderItem={renderGridItem}
        />
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to get LOCATIONS data from the API? Something like this should work (code is untested)

```
const HomeScreen = props => {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getLocations() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-places');
      setLocations(data);
    }
    getLocations();
  }, []);

// ...

  return (
    <>
      {locations && (
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          data={locations}
          renderItem={renderGridItem}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
 };
```

Comment: What does mean {locations && (...)}

Comment: The FlatList component won't render until the locations object is not undefined